# Conditionally wrapping child elements in template without duplication

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a template that needs to be rendered slightly differently depending on a boolean prop. If it's true, the wrapper needs to be outside the child elements, if false, it needs to be wrapping just one of the child elements.

The only way I can think of to do this is to duplicate the child elements in the template like this:

```
<template>
<div>
  <template v-if="flag">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <component-a />
      <component-b />
      <component-c />
    </div>
  </template>

  <template v-if="!flag">
    <component-a />
    <div class="wrapper">
      <component-b />
    </div>
    <component-c />
    </div>
  </template>
</div>
</template>
```

Is there any way to do this without duplicating the `component-[a/b/c]` declarations, which may contain large numbers of props for instance.

Comment: Not an answer, but BTW you can use `v-else` to avoid duplicating the flag!

Comment: By the way, you don't need the general wrapping `<div>` here, as with `v-if="..."` & `v-else` it's always one or the other, meaning only one root element. :) Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about conditional class binding, ref [Class and Style Bindings](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html)

```html
<template>
  <div :class="{ wrapper: flag}">
    <component-a />
    <div :class="{ wrapper: !flag}">
      <component-b />
    </div>
    <component-c />
  </div>
</template>
```

---

**Alternative with named slots (untested)**

Assuming it's worth the trouble of splitting your template into parent and child, I think you can use named slots with the same name in multiple places, provided you use `v-if` to compile-in only one instance at a time.

Ref: [Conditional slots, is it possible](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2009#issuecomment-163934181)

**child**

```html
<template>
<div>
  <template v-if="flag">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <slot name="component-a">
      <slot name="component-b">
      <slot name="component-c">
    </div>
  </template>

  <template v-if="!flag">
    <slot name="component-a">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <slot name="component-b">
    </div>
    <slot name="component-c">
    </div>
  </template>
</div>
</template>
```

**parent**

```html
<child>
  <component-a slot="component-a" />
  <component-b slot="component-b" />
  <component-c slot="component-c" />
</child>
```

Comment: That's definitely an improvement on the template, but it in this case adding this extra `div` in both scenarios is undesirable.

Comment: This is stretching it - I wonder if `<template class="wrapper" is="div" v-if="flag">` works?

Comment: It is great, but what if the components are not coming from the outside, like here, were can juggle with through slots, but are defined on the template directly? Any idea how can a wrapper be added conditionally (as per original question) to, let's say, a pretty damn complex input? Thanks